# How do I set Gradient Texture not to be global in an array?

Tags: materials, texture-painting, color, svg

I created a 3D model from an SVG and now that I set the material of the "play" button to a gradient and create an array, the gradient seems to be global and I want them to have the exact same gradient

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess you need to apply the Array modifier and separate each object

Comment: I tried, but even if I managed to do this, wouldn't I lose performance creating new objects?

Comment: Yes, what you can do is select them all, select one last, and press Ctrl L (Make Links) > Object Data, so that they all share the same mesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid fiddly math with UV offsets in the *Array* modifier, the simplest thing to do might be to unwrap your object from a vertical orthogonal view, with <kbd>U</kbd> Unwrap > 'Project From View (Bounds)':

[image]

Then every array element will carry its own UV coordinates, 0->1 in U:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried this but the gradient was all jagged, I think that is due to the SVG file I used to extrude the struct, maybe I should just create the triangle by hand

Comment: Hi @Pedro! Thanks. The distortted UV might be due to the heavy triangulation of an imported SVG. Try X > 'Limited Dissolve' on the triangle before extruding.